# Egui ScrollArea part of a Rect

Tags: user-interface, rust, egui

I'm trying to create a `ScrollArea` that will have bounds that start at a certain `(x, y)` screen coordinates and end at a `(z, w)` screen coordinates. In other words, I want to create an arbitrary `<div>` (in html terms) that has fixed width and height and is placed in an arbitrary spot on the screen.

What I have right now is this:

[image: Text that is outside of the container, (but with what seems to be correct bounds)]

It appears the text is outside of where the container is, but it seems to have the correct bounds.

Here is what I want the result to look like:
[image: The text is at the same position as the container, and is scrolling with respect to the bounds of the container]

Here's the code I have tried at the moment:

```rs
let rect = Rect::from_min_max(pos2(80.0, 80.0), pos2(280.0, 280.0));
let frame = egui::Frame::none()
    .fill(Color32::from_rgb(232, 12, 232))
    .paint(rect);

ui.painter().add(frame);

egui::ScrollArea::vertical()
    .max_height(280.0 - 80.0)
    .max_width(280.0 - 80.0)
    .show(ui, |ui| {
        ui.add(Label::new("long text".repeat(99)));
    });
```

Full code:

```rs
use eframe::egui::{self, *};

fn main() {
    let native_options = eframe::NativeOptions::default();

    eframe::run_native(
        "Arbitrary Scroll",
        native_options,
        Box::new(|_| Box::new(MyEguiApp)),
    )
    .unwrap();
}

struct MyEguiApp;

impl eframe::App for MyEguiApp {
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, _frame: &mut eframe::Frame) {
        egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
            let rect = Rect::from_min_max(pos2(80.0, 80.0), pos2(280.0, 280.0));
            let frame = egui::Frame::none()
                .fill(Color32::from_rgb(232, 12, 232))
                .paint(rect);

            ui.painter().add(frame);

            egui::ScrollArea::vertical()
                .max_height(280.0 - 80.0)
                .max_width(280.0 - 80.0)
                .show(ui, |ui| {
                    ui.add(Label::new("long text".repeat(99)));
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`egui` uses a sort of cursor to remember where to draw next, but painting does not advance that cursor or influence it in any way. You have to `Ui::allocate_*` to advance the cursor to the correct position. Specifically you can use [`Ui::allocate_ui_at_rect`](https://docs.rs/egui/latest/egui/struct.Ui.html#method.allocate_ui_at_rect) to allocate a specific rect of the remaining surface. And then just render to that.

```rust
impl eframe::App for MyEguiApp {
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, _frame: &mut eframe::Frame) {
        egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
            let rect = Rect::from_min_max(pos2(80.0, 80.0), pos2(280.0, 280.0));
            let frame = egui::Frame::none()
                .fill(Color32::from_rgb(232, 12, 232))
                .paint(rect);

            ui.painter().add(frame);
            ui.allocate_ui_at_rect(rect, |ui| {
                egui::ScrollArea::vertical()
                    .max_height(280.0 - 80.0)
                    .max_width(280.0 - 80.0)
                    .show(ui, |ui| {
                        ui.add(Label::new("long text".repeat(99)));
                    });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, the text doesn't seem to fully fill the bounds of the rectangle, the width is a bit too small, the scrollbar is not on the far right of the rect, and the height is a bit too tall

Here's an image showing what I mean: https://imgur.com/a/dg3uY4K
(I also removed the .max_height and .max_width calls, so that's not the issue)

Comment: Alright, it seems like this is some sort of bug with `ScrollArea` itself, because sometimes, for certain texts, it works fine. Thank you so much for your help!